# Try some changes and rollback to previous state in case of failure in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, rollback

In a game I'm writing there is a player that moves on a board.  On this board there are other objects too.  So I have a bunch of objects each one holding its state.  The player can be asked to move onto a specific adjacent cell.  Its moving is made of three discrete parts:  exiting its current cell; traversing from the current cell to the destination cell; entering the new cell.  Each of these phases may trigger some change of the objects on the board.  The player either perform a full movement or doesn't move at all.  There may be obstacles that prevent the player from reaching the goal cell on each of the three phases.  The problem is to tell if the player can perform the move, and move it if and only if it can.

I first thought that I can inspect if there is no obstacle that prevents the player from exiting its current cell, if there is no obstacle preventing it to traverse towards the goal cell, and if there is no obstacle that prevents it to enter the goal cell.  If all these conditions are matched, then I move the player;  if not, then I don't move the player and the state of the board hasn't changed.

But it's not that simple.  In fact, even if the three tests succeed, the player may be unable to move.  For instance, when it exits its cell a change of the board may be triggered that makes impossible for it to later transition to the goal cell.  In this situation everything must stay the same:  the player shouldn't move (because it can't perform a full move) and the board should stay the same, meaning that no event should be triggered.

Since I can't know if the player can move or not beforehand, but only attempting to move it, I thought about another approach.  I can try to move the player without checking anything beforehand, and rollback to the previous state in case of failure on any of the three moving steps.  The rolling back is necessary because, while trying to move, an event may have been triggered so the board may have changed accordingly.

The question is the following.  How can I try to execute some code that may change the state of some objects and then rollback to the previous state in case something happens?  More concretely, suppose I have a method `move` that returns a boolean, and that changes the state of some objects.  I'd like to keep the changes if the method returns true, otherwise rollback all the changes.  How can such a behaviour be implemented?

Or do you have a better idea to solve the described problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fine approach. Databases do this all the time.

There are, unfortunately, many, *many* answers to this question, and the most appropriate choice amongst these many answers depends on your specific scenario an data storage mechanism.

### Use a database

The simplest one available is databases.

This involves the following setup:

1. Ensure you always use transactions, for everything. Preferably even read-only operations.
2. Ensure you have a non-idiotic database. For example, MySQL MyISAM counts as an idiotic database; don't use that. Most SQL-based DBs are sane in this regard. Avoid mongodb and other such document-based db engines for this specific use-case. You're looking for a database that supports SERIALIZABLE level transactions and actually adheres to the rules of it (vs. many db engines that act like they support it, but don't actually give you the guarantees that SERIALIZABLE describes).
3. Set up your connection to use TransactionLevel.SERIALIZABLE.
4. This inherently means so-called 'retry'. To manage this, you need to wrap any and all code that interacts with databases in a lambda so that the underlying framework can re-run your code if neccessary. In general, do not use JDBC directly, instead use a much nicer abstraction built on top of it. You have two mainstream options: [JOOQ](https://jooq.org) and [JDBI](https://jdbi.org). The tutorials of both of these excellent libraries include details on how to do it right.

Once you have all that, 'fail the operation and change nothing at all' is as easy as exiting your 'do these data operations' (which is a block of code, filled with DB query statements (sql `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE`/`SELECT`), handed to jdbi/jooq) by way of an exception. The transaction will be rolled back and nothing you changed in the DB actually 'sticks'. Also useful: All other code sees the way things were before you started the 'move the player' song and dance routine in one instant, and then in the next, as if everything applied. In other words, the player move ends up acting as if it is atomic, which is presumably a **requirement** for this model to work right. No other code, if ever you make this a multi-threaded setup, should ever act on half-a-move!

If you're not currently using databases, then it gets much, much more complicated. You're more or less signing up to write your own MVCC-style database engine which is not an easy job.

There are a few easier answers. As usual for easy answers, they may be utterly infeasible for your particular use case.

### Immutables / Cloning

If the data structure that describes your game state is 100% immutable (zero setters), or even if not: As long as your 'move the player' code never actually modifies anything at all and is instead operating on / produces new slightly modified clones every step of the process, then 'aborting' is trivial: Just.. return.

The one and only way the game state ever actually updates is if you update the one field that points at an object representing the **entire game state**, which you do at the very end. Changing a reference in java (any non-primitive variable is a reference) is atomic.

If your game state is quite large this is probably a bad idea as it neccessarily involves a *complete* copy.

### Rollback logs

Another option is that every operation you can do to the game state is paired with a mirror implementation that undoes it. Every 'change' you make to the state is described in the form of an Operation object, and each Operation has code inside that both knows how to apply the change to the underlying game state, AND it knows how to un-apply it. Applying may be implemented by way of adding new Operations to the queue.

For example:

```
public class HitCreature extends Operation {
    private Player actor;
    private Creature target;
    private Weapon weapon;

    public void apply() {
       target.health -= actor.getStrength();
        if (weapon.hasKnockBack()) {
          //calculate direction...
          queue.addOperation(new KnockbackCreature(target, direction));
        }
        if (target.isDead()) {
          queue.addOperation(new RemoveCreature(target));
          queue.addOperation(new AddSkeleton(target));
        }
    }

    public void unapply() {
        target.health += actor.getStrength();
    }
}
```

Any given move is simply a single operation that explodes into multiple operations and you maintain a List, with each operation on it, in order. Either you get to the end of this list without any errors in which case, great, it all succeeded. Or, one of the operations fails, in which case, walk back to the 0-index in it, invoking `unapply`, which should *exactly* undo everything it did (and the unapply code CANNOT add new operations, it just undoes what it directly changed without causing any further side-effects).

This is no bueno if you are using multi-threaded code, though.

### Other options

There's more strategies, but these hopefully give you some ideas on where to go from here.

Comment: Thank you very much for all these ideas and your time!